# UWP DataGrid SelectedItem binding not working

Tags: uwp, datagrid, uwp-xaml

I'm trying to deal with a small issue with my UWP app. In the following page, when using the AppBarButton *Edit*, I'd like to bind the selected item of the *DataGrid* as *CommandParameter* but it's not working (the command is called with a null parameter). For a troubleshooting purpose, I've created the *TextBlock* ***MyTextBlock*** whose Text property is bound to the *DataGrid's SelectedItem*. But even after selecting an item, the TextBlok is not updated. Do you see something wrong with the following XAML page?
I has been doing that for years with WPF but cannot get it work with UWP.

Thank you in advance for your suggestions.

```
<Page x:Name="MyPage"
x:Class="MyApp.PageSites"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:WindowsTechnicianClient"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
xmlns:uwp="using:Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls"
xmlns:base="using:Base"
mc:Ignorable="d"
Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
<Page.Resources>
    <local:StaticMapper x:Key="Static"/>
</Page.Resources>
<Page.TopAppBar>
    <CommandBar ClosedDisplayMode="Compact" IsOpen="True">
        <CommandBar.PrimaryCommands>
            <AppBarElementContainer>
                <TextBlock x:Name="MyTextBox" Text="{Binding ElementName=MyDataGridSites, Path=SelectedItem}"/>
            </AppBarElementContainer>
            <AppBarButton Command="{x:Bind CommandEditItem}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=MyDataGridSites, Path=SelectedItem}"
                          Icon="Edit" IsCompact="False" Label="Edit"/>
        </CommandBar.PrimaryCommands>
    </CommandBar>
</Page.TopAppBar>

    <uwp:DataGrid x:Name="MyDataGridSites" AlternatingRowBackground="WhiteSmoke" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                  IsReadOnly="True" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource Static}, Path=Sites}" SelectionMode="Single">
        <uwp:DataGrid.Columns>
            <uwp:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding}" Header="Name"/>
            <uwp:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Type}" Header="Type"/>
            <uwp:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Address}" Header="Address"/>
            <uwp:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Latitude}" Header="Latitude"/>
            <uwp:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Longitude}" Header="Longitude"/>
        </uwp:DataGrid.Columns>
    </uwp:DataGrid>
```

Answer (score 3):

I figured this out:
*CommandParameter="{x:Bind MyDataGridSites.SelectedItem, Mode=OneWay}"*

```
    <Page.Resources>
    <local:StaticMapper x:Key="Static"/>
</Page.Resources>

    <uwp:DataGrid x:Name="MyDataGridSites" AlternatingRowBackground="WhiteSmoke" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                  IsReadOnly="True" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource Static}, Path=Sites}" SelectionMode="Single">
        <uwp:DataGrid.Columns>
            <uwp:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding}" Header="Name"/>
            <uwp:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Type}" Header="Type"/>
            <uwp:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Address}" Header="Address"/>
            <uwp:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Latitude}" Header="Latitude"/>
            <uwp:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Longitude}" Header="Longitude"/>
        </uwp:DataGrid.Columns>
    </uwp:DataGrid>
<Page.TopAppBar>
    <CommandBar ClosedDisplayMode="Compact" IsOpen="True">
        <CommandBar.PrimaryCommands>
            <AppBarButton Command="{x:Bind CommandEditItem}" CommandParameter="{x:Bind MyDataGridSites.SelectedItem, Mode=OneWay}"
                          Icon="Edit" IsCompact="False" Label="Edit"/>
        </CommandBar.PrimaryCommands>
    </CommandBar>
</Page.TopAppBar>
```